# Couldn't install matplotlib.pylot

Tags: python-3.x

So I installed the NumPy, SciPy and Matplotlib on Windows 10, with the following codes. I wanted to install matplotlib.pylot and I got an error message.

I have already tried to reinstalling the matplotlib. Any solutions?

```
(work) C:\DEV>python -m pip install numpy #success
...#success

(work) C:\DEV>python -m pip install scipy #success
...#success

(work) C:\DEV>python -m pip install matplotlib 
...#success

(work) C:\DEV>python -m pip install matplotlib.pyplot
Collecting matplotlib.pyplot
```

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.pyplot (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib.pyplot
```

Comment: What did you google?

Comment: To be precise. I did everything according to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FDa6Kss51Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once, when I encountered this kind of an error, the problem was Python version. Python isn't backwards-compatilbe like Java, you can't just install the most recent version and hope for the best. Please always make sure the software you're trying to download is available for Python you use. If it isn't- downgrade Python.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Wheels](https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild)

```
git clone https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib
git clone https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild
python matplotlib-winbuild\buildall.py
```